# How is OpenDNS blocking my connection on Cellular?

Tags: iphone, ios

I’m wondering if TMobile is using blocking software.

[image]

Is it possible to change my DNS on cellular?

Comment: It can’t. Do you have a Wi-Fi connection, VPN installed, or some other app capable of intercepting DNS requests?

Comment: I was not on wifi - was using cellular, was not using a vpn at the the time. No proxy should have been active, either.

Comment: To avoid this being closed could you edit into the body which hardware you have and which version / build of iOS?